# Eclipse SWT: Switch field using TAB instead of adding space

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, field

Usually, when you press TAB in Eclipse SWT, you switch to the next field. But in certain text-fields it is adding spaces instead of switching the field. How to program this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This normally happens for `StyledText` controls.

Add a Traverse listener to the control and enable traversal for tab:

```
StyledText text = ....

text.addListener(SWT.Traverse, event -> {
     if (event.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_NEXT ||
         event.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_PREVIOUS) {
        event.doit = true;
     }
 });
```